# Error when running the code for Android (FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

my program has this error only when running on Android, and there is no problem when running on Chrome.[

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'

Could not find ddmlib-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddml1b:30.3.0).

Searched in the following locations:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddml1b/30.3.0/ddml1b-30.3.0.jar

Could not find aaptcompiler-7.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build;aaptcompiler:7.3.0).

Searched in the following locations:

e. o/a

7.3.0/optcomptter-7.3.0.3or

Could not find bundletool-1.9.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.9.0).

Searched in the following locations:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.9.0/bundletool-1.9.0.jar

Could not find crash-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:30.3.0).



Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in $7s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
]
```

I changed some codes related to the versions, the error changed but it did not run

Comment: Could you please provide your build.gradle codes too? And pubspec.yaml.